# How to remove the unwanted character like white spaces and newline from a string

Tags: python

Recently i have write down a python script to download the sequences from a database if you provide the accession number (for example Rv1617 ) it will give output as given bellow

```
import wget
import re
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
e = raw_input("Enter the correct accession number.: ")
y = ''.join([i for i in e if i.isdigit()])
#print y
url = "http://tuberculist.epfl.ch/quicksearch.php?gene+name="+y+"&submit=Search#sequence"
#print url
filname = wget.download(url)
a = open(filname,'r')
b = a.readlines()
f = "|"+e+"|"

for c in b:
    if f in c:
        #x = c
        pattern = re.compile("> >.+<br /></")
        z = pattern.findall(c)
        #print z

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_data(self, data):
        final = ''.join(data)
        andfinal = final.replace(" ","")
        print andfinal,
# instantiate the parser and fed it some HTML

for xz in z:
    parser = MyHTMLParser()
    parser.feed(xz)
```

it will download the sequence like this:

```
>>>
Enter the correct accession number.:Rv1617

>>M.tuberculosisH37Rv|Rv1617|pykA
VTRRGKIVCTLGPATQRDDLVRALVEAGMDVARMNFSHGDYDDHKVAYERVRVASDATGR
AVGVLADLQGPKIRLGRFASGATHWAEGETVRITVGACEGSHDRVSTTYKRLAQDAVAGD
RVLVDDGKVALVVDAVEGDDVVCTVVEGGPVSDNKGISLPGMNVTAPALSEKDIEDLTFA
LNLGVDMVALSFVRSPADVELVHEVMDRIGRRVPVIAKLEKPEAIDNLEAIVLAFDAVMV
ARGDLGVELPLEEVPLVQKRAIQMARENAKPVIVATQMLDSMIENSRPTRAEASDVANAV
LDGADALMLSGETSVGKYPLAAVRTMSRIICAVEENSTAAPPLTHIPRTKRGVISYAARD
IGERLDAKALVAFTQSGDTVRRLARLHTPLPLLAFTAWPEVRSQLAMTWGTETFIVPKMQ
STDGMIRQVDKSLLELARYKRGDLVVIVAGAPPGTVGSTNLIHVHRIGEDDV
```

first line is fine but rest of the lines has new line character or spaces which should be remove in output and output should look like this:

```
 >>M.tuberculosisH37Rv|Rv1617|pykA
VTRRGKIVCTLGPATQRDDLVRALVEAGMDVARMNFSHGDYDDHKVAYERVRVASDATGRAVGVLADLQGPKIRLGRFASGATHWAEGETVRITVGACEGSHDRVSTTYKRLAQDAVAGDRVLVDDGKVALVVDAVEGDDVVCTVVEGGPVSDNKGISLPGMNVTAPALSEKDIEDLTFALNLGVDMVALSFVRSPADVELVHEVMDRIGRRVPVIAKLEKPEAIDNLEAIVLAFDAVMV
```

i have tried with :

```
andfinal = final.replace(" ","")
```

it is working for spaces but not for newline char.

Please suggest what changes should i make:

thanks and regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the string on newlines, then re-join the lines:

```
final_lines = final.splitlines()
final = final_lines[0] + '\n' + ''.join(final_lines[1:])
```

Demo:

```
>>> final = '''\
... >M. tuberculosis H37Rv|Rv1617|pykA
... VTRRGKIVCTLGPATQRDDLVRALVEAGMDVARMNFSHGDYDDHKVAYERVRVASDATGR
... AVGVLADLQGPKIRLGRFASGATHWAEGETVRITVGACEGSHDRVSTTYKRLAQDAVAGD
... RVLVDDGKVALVVDAVEGDDVVCTVVEGGPVSDNKGISLPGMNVTAPALSEKDIEDLTFA
... LNLGVDMVALSFVRSPADVELVHEVMDRIGRRVPVIAKLEKPEAIDNLEAIVLAFDAVMV
... ARGDLGVELPLEEVPLVQKRAIQMARENAKPVIVATQMLDSMIENSRPTRAEASDVANAV
... LDGADALMLSGETSVGKYPLAAVRTMSRIICAVEENSTAAPPLTHIPRTKRGVISYAARD
... IGERLDAKALVAFTQSGDTVRRLARLHTPLPLLAFTAWPEVRSQLAMTWGTETFIVPKMQ
... STDGMIRQVDKSLLELARYKRGDLVVIVAGAPPGTVGSTNLIHVHRIGEDDV
... '''
>>> final_lines = final.splitlines()
>>> print final_lines[0] + '\n' + ''.join(final_lines[1:])
>M. tuberculosis H37Rv|Rv1617|pykA
VTRRGKIVCTLGPATQRDDLVRALVEAGMDVARMNFSHGDYDDHKVAYERVRVASDATGRAVGVLADLQGPKIRLGRFASGATHWAEGETVRITVGACEGSHDRVSTTYKRLAQDAVAGDRVLVDDGKVALVVDAVEGDDVVCTVVEGGPVSDNKGISLPGMNVTAPALSEKDIEDLTFALNLGVDMVALSFVRSPADVELVHEVMDRIGRRVPVIAKLEKPEAIDNLEAIVLAFDAVMVARGDLGVELPLEEVPLVQKRAIQMARENAKPVIVATQMLDSMIENSRPTRAEASDVANAVLDGADALMLSGETSVGKYPLAAVRTMSRIICAVEENSTAAPPLTHIPRTKRGVISYAARDIGERLDAKALVAFTQSGDTVRRLARLHTPLPLLAFTAWPEVRSQLAMTWGTETFIVPKMQSTDGMIRQVDKSLLELARYKRGDLVVIVAGAPPGTVGSTNLIHVHRIGEDDV
```

Take into account, however, that the FAST format specifically allows for the newlines, and a decent FASTA format library can interpret the string for you.

Answer (score 0):

Or you may do `replace` twice:

```
w = s.replace('\n', '').replace(' ', '')
```

This will give you the one-line output as well.

Comment: This would remove too many newlines; the OP wants the first newline to be preserved. Moreover, the spaces do not need to be replaced; the OP wants to preserve spaces in the first line, and there are no spaces in the other lines, at all.

Answer (score 0):

The s.strip() is what you are looking for.

if no parameters are supplied, it strips all white space characters including newlines.

Simply read a line at a time, strip and join.

Comment: `str.strip()` removes whitespace *from the start and end*, it will not help the OP with removing whitespace from the middle of a string.

Comment: You are right.  I saw the question as if the new lines were introduced by the readline(). That's why I wrote to read a line at a time.